# python list comprehension that returns a dictionary after doing .split()

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm working on an basic python exercise and I want to split each strings in the following list and map each city to the states. (assuming the state coming after the ',' is correct)

How can I use list comprehension to make this job easier?

```
cities = ['washington,ct', 'springfield,or', 'riverside,tx', 'franklin,vt', 'lebanon,co', 'dayton,tx', 'las vegas,nm', 'madison,ca', 'georgetown,ct', 'los angeles,tx']
```

the desired outcome would be :

```
{'washington': 'ct',
 'springfield': 'or',
 'riverside': 'tx',
 'franklin': 'vt',
 'lebanon': 'co',
 'dayton': 'tx',
 'las vegas': 'nm',
 'madison': 'ca',
 'georgetown': 'ct',
 'los angeles': 'tx'}
```

This is what I did before learning list comprehension

```
splitedList = []
for x in cities:
    splitedList.append(x.split(','))
print(splitedList)

my_dict = dict(splitedList)
print(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `dict` with iterable:

```
dict(s.split(',') for s in cities)
```

Output:

```
{'washington': 'ct',
 'springfield': 'or',
 'riverside': 'tx',
 'franklin': 'vt',
 'lebanon': 'co',
 'dayton': 'tx',
 'las vegas': 'nm',
 'madison': 'ca',
 'georgetown': 'ct',
 'los angeles': 'tx'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cities = {x[0]:x[1] for x in (y.split(",") for y in ('washington,ct', 'springfield,or', 'riverside,tx'))}
```

Comment: I think you meant to write `for y in cities` or else this code is simply equivalent to hard-coding the dictionary...

Comment: Good answer, but note version incompatibility; you need to be using Python >=2.7 or Python >= 3.0.